# Java JTextArea how to apply syntax highlighting

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple code editor with the JFrame library in Java and I've got all the base things working except for syntax highlighting. I've read through forums and forums but I am not able to find anything. So my question is how to change the color of certain words
An example

```java
TextEditor(){
        JTextArea textArea;
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("foo");
        this.setSize(1000,1000);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        textArea=new JTextArea();

        textArea=new JTextArea();

        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        textArea.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.PLAIN,20));
        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textArea);

        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(950,950));
        
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
}
```

Comment: you found nothing because `JTextArea` is the wrong component, please check Oracle's tutorial [Using Text Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) - first diagram shows that `JEditorPane` and `JTextPane` are able to displayed styled text, while `JTestAres` *only* displays plain text.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please eloborate

Comment: The **JTextArea** component *can not* display Syntax Highlighting. You will need to use either the **JEditorPane** component or the **JTextPane** component which can possibly display Syntax Highlighting.

Answer (score -1):

Hey im making a IDE and i can help you :p.
Replace JTextArea by JTextPane : JTextPane can be Stylised.
For the syntax hightlight you can use the [StyledDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68337928/how-to-highlight-words-using-java-highlighter).

Comment: Thanks! That worked but now I can't make t that when one line is full the it moves to the other one and my "open" function has been destroyed as I can't use append. Do you know any workarounds

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).